# Changing Filenet P8 localization after installation

Tags: localization

We installed Filenet-P8 on a localized Windows 2012. We noticed this OS could be set to another language "quickly". Is there a painless way to relocalize the whole system (Windows + Sql Server + FileNet) ? We're experencing dev issues which could be related to Sql Server localization, and are thinking about the best fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to our expert, FileNet P8 is independent from OS localization. We changed it, and it seems to be okay.